# Get aliased table names from SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Given the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE #TestTable
(
    Code varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    Parent varchar(10) NULL
);

INSERT INTO #TestTable
SELECT 'Parent', Null UNION ALL
SELECT 'Child', 'Parent';
```

I want to be able to convert this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM #TestTable child
INNER JOIN #TestTable parent ON ( parent.Code = child.Parent );
```

into this:

```
SELECT child.Code, child.Parent, parent.Code, parent.Parent
FROM #TestTable child
INNER JOIN #TestTable parent ON ( parent.Code = child.Parent );
```

Using [`sp_describe_first_result_set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) I can get close by using this statement:

```
EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set
N'SELECT * 
FROM #TestTable child
INNER JOIN #TestTable parent ON ( parent.Code = child.Parent )', NULL, 2;
```

but it'll return the source table as `#TestTable` instead of `child/parent`.

Comment: Aliases are more of a visual aid for the users, not the RDBMS, The data engine will see the table names, not the aliases, and will treat said aliases as if they were the table. Personally, I see that as a good thing, as you can alias a table as anything, and *some* people use very poor aliasing.

Comment: Maybe so, but you'd get a SQL error `The multi-part identifier xx could not be bound` if you used the same column/table name twice, therefore you'd need the alias regardless.

Comment: Although you could parse the query client-side using the T-SQL script DOM to extract the table and aliases names and map to `sp_describe_first_result_set`, that will be non-trivial for more complex queries when the same table is used more than once.

Comment: @DanGuzman Sorry, the T-SQL DOM?

Comment: I believe Dan's referring to [`TSqlParser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.tsqlparser?view=sql-dacfx-140.3881.1) and friends. Powerful if not exactly trivial to use, but still easier than processing T-SQL from within T-SQL. If you just want to expand `*` in queries, [SSDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt) aka Database Projects has a powerful refactoring option for that (among other goodies, like verifying object existence).

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the TSqlParser available in this [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.DacFx.x64/). Thanks for jumping in @JeroenMostert.

Comment: Ah, thanks, had a feeling it was something like that.  Unfortunately I am sitting on the database side with this one and need to extrapolate the columns in real time.  Looks like I'll need to build a parser myself.  So sad because `sp_describe_first_result_set` came so close, if only there was an option 3.  Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

If the only thing you care about is looking at which table is the source table you could split the data in to 2 temporary tables, that way you will affect the source_table returned by your system stored procedure call.

```
CREATE TABLE #TestTable
(
    Code varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    Parent varchar(10) NULL
);

INSERT INTO #TestTable
SELECT 'Parent', Null UNION ALL
SELECT 'Child', 'Parent';

select * into #Parent from #TestTable where code='Parent';

select * into #Child from #TestTable where Code='Child';

EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set
N'SELECT * 
FROM #Child child
INNER JOIN #Parent parent ON ( parent.Code = child.Parent )', NULL, 2;


drop table #TestTable, #Parent, #Child;
```

[image]

Comment: I like this, it's an interesting point of view so +1 from me :)